# Typescript v8 natives syntax Expression expected

Tags: typescript, v8

Using Typescript 4.1.2 is it possible to compile code that references the functions one calls when the `--allow-natives-syntax` flag in v8 is set?

For example:

```
function foo(bar: ()=>void)): void {
    %OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(bar); // --> TS1109; Expression expected
}
```

Neither `//@ts-ignore` nor `//@ts-expect-error` silence this error

Comment: Please keep in mind that using `%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall` in a way that does _not_ degrade performance is extremely difficult. This function is meant for testing, where triggering certain internal mechanisms is more important than achieving high performance. For regular operation, V8's default behavior is almost guaranteed to give you better outcomes. In particular, optimization only makes sense if sufficient type feedback has been collected beforehand. Optimization on the very first execution is *always* counter-productive.

Comment: Thank you jmrk. I agree with everything you're saying. I'm just toying around and exploring, trying to get a feel for when v8 stops trying to untangle my spaghetti monsters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have boilerplate to test v8 natives, so I don't know if it works, but You can try next piece of code

```
function foo(bar: () => void): void {
  //@ts-ignore
  ((void 0) %OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(bar));
}
```

Don't judge me) I'm just trying to help)

Comment: I feel stupid for not thinking of this!. Good suggestion captain

Comment: @RyderBrooks you should not, I felt stupid during writing this answer ))))

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use `eval`

```
function foo(bar: ()=>void)): void {
    eval('%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall(bar)');
}
```