# TypeScript "Expression expected" errors despite @ts-ignore on lines with Google Apps Script force-printing scripts

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, google-apps-script, template-engine

I'm writing code for a Google Apps Script module using VSCode, which otherwise works well in checking syntax and so on.

The only problem is, this produces 5 TS errors, despite the `@ts-ignore`:

```
    // @ts-ignore
    const { a, b } = <?!= JSON.stringify(my_incoming_template_data) ?>;
```

It's the `<?!` and `?>` that it's complaining about.  Those demarcate Google Apps Script [force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets). *

I've tried [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65189996/16777) specific to `@ts-ignore` but apparently not specific enough (to force-printing scriptlets.)  I do not wish to disable TS for the entire file with `@ts-nocheck` because it's useful for TS to help with the rest of the file.

How can I force TS to listen to the `@ts-ignore` command?  (Or support force-printing scriptlets?)

* Before you point it out :)...in my case, I *do* need to use because I'm generating HTML source code intended to be seen by the script user.  (I realize this is an unusual case; nonetheless, it *is* what's needed.)

Comment: FWIW,  It's still a error to unpack strings to two variables.  I don't think it'll work. Secondly, if you're just using type checking, you're probably using tslint? In which case, there are tslint specific error blockers

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks, but actually, unpacking works fine.  It's only TS that complains.  Anyway, that's besides the point: My question is how to silence the superfluous errors.  I'll look into the tslint angle though, thanks for the lead!  (It's been a while since I set that part of it up.)  ✔

Comment: Hmm, the standard trick of surrounding with `/* tslint:disable */` and `/* tslint:enable */` has no effect.  I don't see any .tsconfig anywhere in this project...I did install GAS types via npm, but maybe otherwise for TS linting it's relying on defaults somehow?

Comment: @Kev ! Did you get an idea of how to resolve it finally?